# Which is better: call a function or type the script out in full, inline?

Tags: javascript, performance

EDIT: Some people (actually, I think everyone who kindly took the time to help :) ) have misconstrued this as a question about how I should go about coding in this situation. My bad. It's not. Don't code like this, people, otherwise you will make the baby Jesus cry. I was asking about how Javascript uses memory, and how (in)efficient code is handled by the browswer. Thanks to Joe for persevering long enough with me to work out what I was asking, and to Adeneo for showing how it should be done. Now, back to the question....

Let's say I have this code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">List item 2</a></li>
  ....snip....
  <li><a onclick="myFunction(this.innerHTML)">List item 1000</a></li>
</ul>
```

I also have, in a script tag:

```
function myFunction(myString) {
  console.log(myString);
  console.log(myString);
  console.log(myString);
}
```

Is this more memory efficient than:

```
<ul>
  <li><a onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML);console.log(this.innerHTML);console.log(this.innerHTML);">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML);console.log(this.innerHTML);console.log(this.innerHTML);">List item 2</a></li>
  ....snip....
  <li><a onclick="console.log(this.innerHTML);console.log(this.innerHTML);console.log(this.innerHTML);">List item 1000</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not bothered by the extra dev time needed for the all the typing required for the second example, as the code is being generated in AngularJS. It would seem to me that the first way would take up less memory, but I keep seeing the second method being used. Is it all the same to the browser at run-time?

EDIT: As Adeneo has stated below, any coder worth his or her salt would use .addEventListener for this example.

Comment: None of the above, use a proper event handler and remove the inline JS

Comment: Read up on [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: Adeneo, I understand, but I'm asking for the pros and cons of these particular methods. And Meager, I feel your pain, but the increased emphasis on mobile development means I am seeing this a lot these days. Unobtrusive javascript is an elegant and important way to present a page, but it is a view that fewer seem to share, nowadays. :(

Comment: And I answered, they are all bad !

Comment: Yeah, sorry, Adeneo, I didn't make that clear. So I shall. These two methods suck. But which uses less memory at runtime. Are we cool now? :)

Comment: It should really not be a matter about memory or run-time, it should rather be a question about maintainable code...

Comment: Why don't you profile both in Chrome, and you'll find out, something tells me difference is so small that you never ever have to worry about it.

Comment: Jonast92, cheers, but maintainability is not an issue. This is becaue my question, a) uses a fanciful example, b) was prompted by a question I asked myself when I saw an AngularJS generated HTML snippet (i.e. only one (li) is coded, and then reused as required), so there is only one line of inline javascript coded, even if it appears a thousand times in the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cared about squeezing every byte and clock cycle out of the computer, you wouldn't be writing JavaScript and you wouldn't be writing a web app. I'm assuming you don't, but are trying to be conscientious.

I think this is misguided. You have a lot of other concerns much more important than this. The first will use less memory, probably, and may involve less work at execution, but that doesn't matter at all.

One important factor in writing code is maintainability. You will achieve this by writing less code and re-using it.

Comment: Cheers, Joe, but this is obviously just a pretend example. I am working on an application that runs to several thousand lines of list items, and I wanted to know how the memory is used. Thank you for confirming that the first method should use less memory, but could you explain why there is less work at execution?

Comment: Hi Jez. It's not obvious that this is a pretend example! You get all kinds of questions here.

Comment: If you declare a function 3 times then it has to be parsed 3 times. Each takes CPU to parse and memory to store. If you declare it once, you only store it once. If the VM optimises (V8 is very clever) then it will have a better chance if there's a single function called many times than a lot of copies of the same function. There are also questions of locality of reference when you increase the number of functions. In nearly all cases these shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I should have kept my mouth shut about the fact I was generating a similar piece of code with AngularJS and just let the question stand on its own. I only mentioned it as, in AngularJS, it's actually quicker to dev the second example than the the first, providing it's using ng-repeat on the (li)s.

Comment: Perhaps you could have another go at the question. I'm not clear on precisely what you're asking. Could you include some 'real' code?

Comment: I wanted to know about the memory usage, and whether, at run-time, there was a difference between the two methods, or if they were effectively the same. I don't have any 'real' code. It was just prompted by seeing some early protoype code that had an onclick on over a thousand (li)s in it, just for demo purposes, and it got me thinking.

Comment: I think the answer is that the first approach, writing a function once and calling it many times (vs writing the same function out many times) is best for a number of reasons. Maintainability, CPU and memory efficiency, page size (loading and storing) etc.

Comment: Thank you. CPU, memory efficiency, and page size. Those are suitable answers for the question. Cheers!

Comment: If this answered your question, give it a tick.

Answer (score 4):

Stop using inline JS, and write code with proper event handlers

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="list_item">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="list_item">List item 2</a></li>
  ........
  <li><a href="#" class="list_item">List item 1000</a></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('list_item');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click',function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    },false);
}
```

note: add attachEvent for older IE

***EDIT:***

Or.... If you really have 1000 elements, you can save more by delegating the event to one single parent element, like so :

```
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
  ........
  <li><a href="#">List item 1000</a></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
var ul = document.getElementById('myUL');

ul.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
        console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
},false);
```

That's one event handler for all the elements !

Comment: I've edited my comment to make it clear that you should addEventListener, so as not to spread bad habits. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning event delegation WITHOUT the jQuery wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use either of the techniques you've proposed.

Here are my priorities in writing code (in order):

1. Correct code (works, no bugs, handles desired edge cases)
2. Maintainable, descriptive, clear and easy to follow or modify code.
3. Compact, concise [DRY code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself).
4. Fast code.

Typically, if you do the first three items, there maybe zero, one or two places where you actually need to worry about performance.  You should never worry about performance before worrying about the other three items before it.  And, only worry about performance when you have actual measured evidence that you have a performance issue and you need to do something about it.  Over time, you will learn techniques that are correct, maintainable, compact and fast and you can do them all at once.  But, the last thing you should do is worry about speed before the other items.

In your specific case, what I would suggest separating your code from your HTML and doing it like this:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a>List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a>List item 2</a></li>
  ....snip....
  <li><a>List item 1000</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
    // add click handlers to the links in my list
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("#myList a");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            // put any code here for the event handler
            // the this pointer will refer to the DOM item that was clicked on
            console.log(this.innerHTML);
        });
    }
</script>
```

As for memory usage, a good general rule of thumb is that less code will occupy less memory so repeating code blocks is generally less efficient than sharing a common block of code.  If you follow the DRY principles, that will get you going down the right path.  Like my comments about speed, I generally try to write code that is efficient (not wasting memory), but I don't spend time trying to optimize memory usage unless I know or suspect that I have a specific issue with memory usage in a particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Learn and start using jQuery. It will save you a lot of work, which should be your biggest concern. Working example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready( function()
{
    $( "a" ).on( "click", function( event )
    {
        console.log( this.innerHTML );
    });
});
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
  ........
  <li><a href="#">List item 1000</a></li>
</ul>
```